# How do i disable Kubernetes Service IP address range using terraform while creating EKS cluster

Tags: terraform

how do i disable or off kubernetes service ip range in terraform. Not able to find relevant article in terraform documentation. It would be grate help if someone provide any suggestion. Looking forward to hear back.

expecting answers from the community.

Comment: Please make sure you read this first: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.